# Must I specify the provider argument for each resource when I'm working on more than one region?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to write the terraform code to create 2 vpc in different regions and one subnet for each vpc.

```
provider "aws" {
    region = "eu-central-1"
    alias = "frankfurt"
}

provider "aws" {
    region = "eu-north-1"
    alias = "stockholm"
}
```

This is what I did to define the regions. Then I created the vpcs successfully with this code block:

```
resource "aws_vpc" "main_vpc" {
    cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
    provider = aws.frankfurt

    tags = {
      Name = "MainVPC"
    }
}

resource "aws_vpc" "second_vpc" {
    cidr_block = "10.1.0.0/16"
    provider = aws.stockholm

    tags = {
      Name = "SecondVPC"
    }
}
```

As you can see, I used provider argument for deploy these vpcs in different regions. Here is the subnet code block:

```
resource "aws_subnet" "main_vpc_subnet" {
    vpc_id = aws_vpc.main_vpc.id

    // cidr block of the vpc was 10.0.0.0/16   
    cidr_block = "10.0.1.0/24"
    availability_zone = "eu-central-1a"
}

resource "aws_subnet" "second_vpc_subnet" {
    vpc_id = aws_vpc.second_vpc.id

    // cidr block of the vpc was 10.1.0.0/16   
    cidr_block = "10.1.1.0/24"
    availability_zone = "eu-north-1a"
}
```

Now, what I thought at this point is that I have already used provider argument for my vpcs, then I don't really need to use the provider argument in my subnets because I already used it in vpc code block. But it didn't work, `Invalid provider configuration` error popped up. I used provider argument in subnets and it worked this time, but I wonder if using provider argument over and over again is just repeating the same code and is there any other ways to avoid it. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you are deploying a configuration that goes across multiple regions, you will need to tell Terraform which region each resource should be deployed into. You could get away with only specifying it on half of the resources by omitting the declaration on the resources that are going into the default region, but I would personally find that to be a good source of bugs and avoid it.

Depending on your situation, you may instead be able to define just a set of resources that go into a single region then deploy it twice - once for Frankfurt, then again for Stockholm. This would work if you are duplicating the same setup across both regions. You can do this just at a module level too - if you have a subset of your resources that are duplicated between the two regions, then you can define them in a module and just [specify the provider for the whole module](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/module-providers).